# Install qt5 separate module

Tags: qt5

i use ubuntu for my project and i need QT5Quick module ONLY(!) for it. Is it possible to install separate module (QT5Quick QT5Dbus Qt5XML) by using "apt-get install" without installing full QT5?
 If it is possible, please, tell me the list of libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Qt 5 package individually, (usually) required dependency will be installed too.

For Qt Quick, you need modules : core, gui, qml, quick, network. xml and dbus just need core (I think so)